# How to get line numbers when warning with Data::Dumper result?

Tags: perl, data-dumper

`warn` behaves differently in the following two cases:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

warn "string";
warn Dumper("string");
```

The first prints:

```
string at dumper.pl line 6.
```

And the second prints just:

```
$VAR1 = 'string';
```

without any line number.

How get the line number when warning with the Dumper result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just connect a string after the Dumper call:

```
warn Dumper("string").' ';
```

yields

```
$VAR1 = 'string';
  at /tmp/execpad-a668561a2ac4/source-a668561a2ac4 line 7.
```

at [eval.in](https://eval.in/459442).

Answer (score 5):

The reason for the difference is because the string ends with a new line.

```
warn "test";
warn "test\n";
```

Output from `Dumper` includes a linefeed, so concat anything on the end will do it.

Or just explicitly reference `__LINE__`:

```
warn Dumper ("error") . "at line:" .__LINE__."\n";
```

(See [`perldoc warn`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/warn.html))

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation for the `warn` function:

```
$ perldoc -f warn

warn LIST
        Prints the value of LIST to STDERR. If the last element of LIST
        does not end in a newline, it appends the same file/line number
        text as "die" does.

        (... and much more information that is worth reading ...)
```

In your case, the output of `Dumper()` ends with a newline, so the file/line number is not printed.